# Python group by is creating list of lists instead of a single list

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'UserName':['LoveLearn','JakeSanz','LoveLearn'],'Alias':['LL','JS','LL'],'ClassRoom1':['A2','3B','C2'],'ClassRoom2':['B5','E6','D2'],'Points':[1,6,2]})
```

I want to group by UserName, Alias and sum the points (done) and get a list of all the classrooms a user has attended.

First I filter the classrom columns by name:

```
classroom_columns = list(data.filter(regex='ClassRoom*').columns)
```

I group the data:

```
grouped_data = data.groupby(['UserName','Alias'])
```

Define this function:

```
def group_metrics(g_df,class_cols):
    return pd.DataFrame({'TotalPoints':g_df['Points'].sum(),'TotalClassRooms':g_df.apply(lambda x: x[class_cols].values.tolist())})
```

But after calling the function

```
group_metrics(grouped_data,classroom_columns)
```

I get a list of lists on the TotalClassRooms:

```
    UserName Alias  TotalPoints       TotalClassRooms
0   JakeSanz    JS            6            [[3B, E6]]
1  LoveLearn    LL            3  [[A2, B5], [C2, D2]]
```

I would want a single list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) before [`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to flatten the DataFrame into 1D:

```
import numpy as np


def group_metrics(g_df, class_cols):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'TotalPoints': g_df['Points'].sum(),
        'TotalClassRooms': g_df.apply(
            lambda x: np.ravel(x[class_cols]).tolist())
    })
```

Or [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
def group_metrics(g_df, class_cols):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'TotalPoints': g_df['Points'].sum(),
        'TotalClassRooms': g_df.apply(
            lambda x: x[class_cols].values.flatten().tolist())
    })
```

---

```
group_metrics(grouped_data, classroom_columns)
```

```
                 TotalPoints   TotalClassRooms
UserName  Alias                               
JakeSanz  JS               6          [3B, E6]
LoveLearn LL               3  [A2, B5, C2, D2]
```